# SAS export into Oracle database with autoincremental ID

Tags: oracle, sas, auto-increment

i am using SAS Data Integration Studio 4.4.
I have a table filled with values there, which i want to export into an oracle database.
The connection to the database and the exporting itself is no problem. But the column "ID" should count up with every new row. How to solve this problem on SAS side?

I can't add an autoincrement on the database for the ID for certain reasons.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should add a new column on the SAS side and handle the incrementing yourself.  I'm not familiar with DIS; do you have access to the SAS Data Step?

Comment: @Joe What do you mean by "handle the incrementing yourself"? Do you mean the monotonic() function? I need to know the last ID of the oracle table to increment correctly in SAS with monotonic(), right? How do i get the last ID from an oracle Table in this case?

Comment: I would never use `monotonic()` in production code, it was never officially released and could cause unexpected results.  I would do it in a SAS data step, if you have access to the SAS data step environment inside DIS - hence my question, do you?

Comment: From [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/092-2009.pdf) it sounds like you do, so i'll make an answer based on that assumption.

Comment: Since I am new to SAS, i don't know exact what you mean. Sorry for that. If you mean access to the "Code"-Section with data step environment. Yes, i have access to data step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a code editor, you should be able to do something approximately like this.  These assume you already have `oralib` defined as your connection to oracle (in a libname statement or DIS's equivalent).

```
* Get last ID in oracle into a macro variable;

proc sql;
select max(id) into :maxID from oralib.oratable;  *make these the real oracle libname and oracle table name;
quit;

*use it;
data append_to_oracle;
set your_data_set; *whatever dataset contains the data you want to insert into oracle;
ID = _n_+&maxID.; *&maxID. contains the highest ID in oracle, so this will add 1 or more to it;
run;
*you could make this a view to save processing time if that is important - like so;
*replace data line with;
*data append_to_oracle/view=append_to_oracle;

*append to oracle however you currently append;
```

`_N_` is the data step loop counter and acts similar to an autoincremented column when doing simple datasteps (always starting at 1).

If your oracle table is large, such that the `max(id)` query might take a while, you might consider saving the max ID in a text file or similar locally so you don't have to keep querying it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am getting the error 22-322: Syntax error, excepting one of the following: "BUFFERSIZE, CHECK, ..." I am trying to find the mistake atm. The error occurs at the select statement.

Comment: That suggests you left off the semicolon after `proc sql`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there is no way to thank someone via a pm or a thanks-button. So I will show my gratitude here.